# cbind a list matrices keeping unique columns

Tags: r, list, matrix, reduce

I have a list of matrices, which among the list elements some of the columns are redundant and I want to Reduce that list into a single matrix keeping only unique columns.

Here's an example data:

```
set.seed(1)
#starting matrix
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10*6),nrow=10,dimnames=list(NULL,c("a_1","a_2","b_1","b_2","c_1","c_2")))
mat.list <- list(mat[,c(1,2,3,4)],mat[,c(1,2,5,6)],mat[,c(3,4,5,6)])
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
res.mat <- Reduce(cbind,mat.list)
```

But that will keep unique columns (in this example, returning exactly `mat`)

Comment: try `m1 <- do.call(cbind, mat.list);
 identical(mat, m1[, !duplicated(colnames(m1))
])[1] TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce(function(x,y)cbind(x,y[,!colnames(y)%in%colnames(x)]),mat.list)
             a_1         a_2         b_1         b_2        c_1        c_2
 [1,] -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737  1.35867955 -0.1645236  0.3981059
 [2,]  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630 -0.10278773 -0.2533617 -0.6120264
 [3,] -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498  0.38767161  0.6969634  0.3411197
 [4,]  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170 -0.05380504  0.5566632 -1.1293631
 [5,]  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575 -1.37705956 -0.6887557  1.4330237
 [6,] -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874 -0.41499456 -0.7074952  1.9803999
 [7,]  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551 -0.39428995  0.3645820 -0.3672215
 [8,]  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238 -0.05931340  0.7685329 -1.0441346
 [9,]  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006  1.10002537 -0.1123462  0.5697196
[10,] -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156  0.76317575  0.8811077 -0.1350546
```